# ERROR: failed to build gem native extension, Linux virtual machine

Tags: ruby, linux, amazon-web-services, mechanize

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0p645 on a Linux AWS.

I tried running `gem install mechanize`, but got this error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mechanize:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lstdc++... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
g++ -I. -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby/2.0 -I.   -fPIC -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -mtune=generic -m64 -o unf.o -c unf.cc
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [unf.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /path/to/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /path/to/.gem/ruby/2.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.1/ext/unf_ext/gem_make.out
```

How do I fix this so I can install `mechanize` on my virtual box?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might need to install libstdc++. For Debian or Ubuntu try:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libstdc++6
```

and then retry installing the gem.